# Facebook Graph API only gets RSVP'd events when i want all?

Tags: php, facebook

**I'm trying to use the Facebook Graph API to get all the events I'm invited to**, (i used to be able to do this with the old facebook api's `events.get()` but that no longer works).

I've been trying for over a day now and the facebook-frustraction is getting critical!

Using the following I can get 248 of my events going way back to 2006, however these are only events where i have clicked `'attending'` `'maybe'` or `'not attending'`, I would like to get **all** the events.

```
$target= 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/events?limit=2000&fields=privacy,end_time,name,picture,location&access_token=' . $access_token;
$page =  file_get_contents($target);
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Possibly can be solved with the answer from your other question?

Comment: you want to gel all the events, despite their rsvp, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like this is not possible.
see the answer from an administrator on: http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=307797